# in android How to update Activity if any network changes

Tags: android

In my app I have 4 activities. if any network changes i want update the activity which is in foreground state. i wrote one broadcast receiver for network changes.  but I want to update activity from that broadcast receiver.

This is my broadcast receiver:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
            // i need to update activity ?????
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Send special Intent to activity to update it. But Question about "update activity" is very wide.

Comment: in activity need to display no network connection if network not available.

Comment: Ok so do you want to change a text that shows network status  ?

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file :

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    ....
</application>
```

then Create this class to store current activity context:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
    }

    private static Activity mCurrentActivity = null;
    public static Activity getCurrentActivity(){
          return mCurrentActivity;
    }
    public static void setCurrentActivity(Activity mCurrentActivity){
          this.mCurrentActivity = mCurrentActivity;
    }
}
```

Create a new Activity :

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {
    protected MyApp mMyApp;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMyApp = (MyApp)this.getApplicationContext();
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMyApp.setCurrentActivity(this);
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        clearReferences();
        super.onPause();
    }
    protected void onDestroy() {        
        clearReferences();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void clearReferences(){
        Activity currActivity = mMyApp.getCurrentActivity();
        if (currActivity != null && currActivity.equals(this))
            mMyApp.setCurrentActivity(null);
    }
}
```

then :

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
            // i need to update activity ?????
            TextView tv = (TextView)myApp.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
            tv.setText("Network is available");
        }
    }
}
```